# How to pass data to the variable from useState after images have been loaded?

Tags: reactjs

I'm really stuck with this simple task, because I'm stupid and newbie in coding. Could you help me to solve it. I'm trying to add array of ids to the gallery variable after images have been loaded.

```
const [ multipleUploadMutation, { data } ] = useMutation(MULTIPLE_UPLOAD_MUTATION);

const [gallery, setGallery] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(gallery);
},[gallery]);

// destructuring IDs from loaded images to pass them to the setGallery.
const images = data?.multipleUpload.map(({data}) => Number(data.id));

// uploading images from file input
const onChange = ({ target: { validity, files } }) => {
    if (validity.valid) {
        multipleUploadMutation({ 
            variables: { 
                files: files,
            },
        });
    }
}; 

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setGallery(images); // I know, this is a wrong way to add images to the gallery varibale, because it is called at the same time as variables.
    createProduct({
        variables: {
            input: {
                title: title,
                gallery: gallery
            }
        },
    });
};
```